# Disable the auto-save of an excel workbook in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, autosave

I would like to disable the autosave option of excel shared workbook in C#, typically when the user is using Sharepoint / OneDrive.

I don't really care about the autorecover option. I'm pointing this out because most of all I can see on the internet is about it.

I have found the [Workbook.AutoUpdateSaveChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.autoupdatesavechanges.aspx) property, which seems to be what I need.
However when I try to set it to false, I'm getting a COMException error I don't understand:
[image: COMException]

HRESULT : 0x800A03EC doesn't seem to be very specific, from what I understand it's basically a common failure code, and I didn't find anything related on the internet.

Now, here is what I tried:

```
if (Application.ActiveWorkbook.AutoUpdateSaveChanges) // COMException here
{
    MessageBox.Show("MyWarning", "WarningTitle");
    return;
}
```

I've tried to work this around but I'm always getting the same error and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

How can I disable, or at least detect the AutoUpdate when it's on? Is the autosave locked when using Sharepoint or any shared worbook?

Comment: You may not care but the users do, a LOT. The typical scenario is *NOT* for SharePoint or OneDrive. It's meant to safeguard local, non-shared work. It's a standard feature for almost all document-based applications, introduced in the 1990s. Even Sublime Text autosaves. What are you really trying to do and why do you think you have to disable auto-save?

Comment: And what do you mean by `Excel Shared Workbooks`? It could mean that two or more users have opened the same file that's saved on a local disk or network share. Or it could mean an Excel file stored in a SharePoint doument library. In that case the way the file is opened is *very* different*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for answering me. Actually, I don't want to completely disable the option, I just want to do it at a specific time where the add-in I'm developping needs to applies changes to the users workbook. I need the file not to be synchronized in order to get a proper output, but I would enable the autosave back after computing. The user is unable to modify the workbook when the add-in is this state by the way.
By "Excel Shared Workbook", I only meant the file is in a OneDrive folder and is automatically autosaved. It is not when using a workbook in a non-shared folder.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also, what I don't "care about" is the autorecover option, because I don't want to do anything with it. I didn't mean I don't care about what the user needs or anything like that. It's just that everything I looked up on the internet was about enabling or disabling the autorecover, and I believe this is not what I need.

Comment: so the *real* problem is a bug in the addin. Breaking the product and risking users' work isn't a viable fix. What are you trying to do? Why does your code conflict with auto-save? That's what needs fixing

Comment: And you *do* care about the users - they pay you. If they discover you lost their work they won't pay you, they may fire you or sue you

Comment: I read you and I understand. I'm not excluding the issue probably is my way to approach the problem, your suggestions are welcome.
Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
The user is doing stuff on his workbook (in my case, it's only 1 user/workbook at a time but they want to synchronize it to allow others to modify it later). At some point, he needs my add-in to compute what he has done. The add-in will apply modifications on the workbook, save it as another file, and reload the original file for him. When the autosave is on, the changes my add-in makes are saved onto the original file as well.

Comment: that's a bug in how you make the modifications. Create a *copy*, modify the copy, save the copy

Comment: If you are wondering why I'm not using a copy of the original file, the reason is that so far the add-in was working this way, I'm trying not to break it up by doing major changes to the process. I am considering doing it but I can't do it on my own yet. Also, shared workbooks seems to be converted into a special format (or at least OneDrive does process them), and I don't have a "safe location" to create a copy. I wouldn't want the copy to be synchronized with Sharepoint as well.
EDIT: well you said what I thought you'd said, here is the answer. But I'm strongly considering it.

Comment: OneDrive works with *local* files. It doesn't make any changes to the folders nor does it affect the format of the files. You *do* have a safe location, it's the TEMP directory. The safe approach for *any* application is to create a copy there, modify the copy and then move it to its final location.

Comment: My apologies then, I didn't know that. I'm a complete newbie with shared files. I will look into it, and since disabling the autosave would be wrong, from what you said, I'll talk my boss out of it. Thanks for your help !

Comment: This has nothing to do with shared files. If the user hit `Save` while the addin run you'd also encounter the same problem. If Excel or the machine crashed, next time the user opened Excel he would see the *modified* files in the autorecovery list, not his own work. If *any* file sync software run, you'd also see invalid copies - and a copy of the temp files used.